# How many ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers satify the following equation $1/a+1/b=1/120$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So far I've only agebra bashed it, as there seems to be no other way of solving it. Am I missing some key insight into this equation so I can solve it, preferably not using algebra?

Comment: By algebra bashing, you mean, like solving for $a$ and thinking about divisibility?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac 1a + \frac 1b & = \frac1{120}\qquad \implies a,b >120\\
\frac {b+a}{ab} & = \frac1{120}\\
\frac {ab}{b+a} & = 120\\
ab & = 120(a+b)\\
ab - 120 a & = 120b\\
a(b-120) & = 120b\\
(b-120) & = \frac{120b}{a}\\
\text{Similarly } \quad(a-120) & = \frac{120a}{b} = \frac {120^2}{b-120}\\
(a-120)(b-120) &= 120^2\\
\end{align}

Now find the factors of $120^2$...

For example $(9,1600)$ is a factor pair of $120^2$ so $(a,b)=(129,1720)$ is a solution. Or $60 \times 240 = 120^2$ gives $(a,b)=(180,360)$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac 1a + \frac 1b = \frac 1{120}$

$120 = \frac 1{\frac 1a + \frac 1b} = \frac {ab}{b+a}$

Let $p$ be a prime that divides $b+a$.  then $p|ab$ so $p|a$ or $p|b$.  So $p|a$ and $p|b$.

Let $\gcd(a,b) = d$ then $\frac {ab}{b+a}= \frac {\frac {ab}d}{\frac bd + \frac ad}$.  But $\frac bd$ and $\frac ad$ have no factors in common and as a sum will not have any factors in common with $\frac {ab}d$ unless $\frac bd$ + $\frac ad=1$ or $2$ and $\frac bd = \frac ad = 1$.

So $a = b$.

So $\frac {ab}{a+b} = \frac {a^2}{2a} = \frac a2 = 120$ so $a = b = 240$ is the only solution.

Comment: Ah... no, it isn't the only solution... try eg. $(180,360)$, $(129,1720)$ (see my answer)